# How to go to next line in Dialogflow responses

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxYOm.png)

[

1. I want to add a new line after "the following things" as \n or other things are not working

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgjV7.png)

Comment: Where are you applying the new line? In Intents -> Responses? Or Fulfillment -> Inline editor? If this is written in code can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you've used Dialogflow's web demo integration option which **DOESN'T** support multiple messages(lines) per response. This integration only supports single text responses.

You can use DialogFlow messenger integration if you want to add multiple messages.
[image: Dialogflow Messenger view]

Answer (score 2):

To make a line break in the 'Text Response' sector just press 'Shift + Enter'.

Para realizar un salto de linea en el sector de 'Text Response' solo hay que presionar 'Shift + Enter'